# Initialise/clear the list contents every time processor is invoked

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

Following is my step configuration

```
// Step
@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, Processor myProcessor,
        Writer myWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                             .<InputObject, List<ProcessedObject>>chunk(15)
                             .reader()
                             .processor(myProcessor)
                             .writer(myWriter)
                             .build();
}
```

I am reading a file based on chunk size and doing the necessary processing in my processor. However, I need the writer to keep track of all the items it has processed, hence I am passing my writer a list of items that need to written to different files depending upon some processed conditions.

My processor:

```
private List<ProcessedObject> processedList;

@Override
public List<ProcessedObject> process(InputObject input) throws Exception {
    ProcessedObject o = new ProcessedObject();
    try{
         //set metadata to processed object
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        o.setErrorFlag(true);
        o.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }
    processedList.add(o);
    return processedList;
}
```

How do I initialise/clear my processed list so that it contains only items belonging to that chunk? Since it's a class level variable, every time it reaches my writer, it contains data from previous chunk as well.

Comment: This is just wrong. As it will return a list of lists eventually. Why do you need to keep track of the processed items? What is the usecase? The processor should just set the metadata not change it to a list.

Comment: The use case is that i want to read data from a file and then process it and the write that transformed object into a different file @M.Deinum

Comment: But why do you need to keep track of the read items? With what you describe i see no need for that list but more of a simple processor. I don't get why you are keeping a list in your processor becuase your writer needs to know all elements? Where does that requirement come from? What is it you are trying to do. Until now the only thing you added to Spring Batch is confusion and a complex processor which you don't need (you could simply enrich the `InputObject` and return it. The write will eventually get the whole chunk.

Comment: Writer gets invoked after the entire chunk size is processed, isn't it? please correct me if am wrong here. I need list of processed sections every time my writer is invoked so that i can write it to a separate file.

Comment: Your writer already receives the full chunk. I see no need for the list, seems like you are over complicating things.

Comment: Ah ok, let me try that

Comment: Looks like you were right, i was just overcomplicating things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html#write(org.springframework.batch.item.Chunk)) receives a `Chunk`, which is a wrapper around a `List` of elements. All the elements that are read and processed are already in that `Chunk`.

Your `ItemProcessor` will process each individual item from the `ItemReader`, Spring Batch will collect them until the chunk size (or the end) is reached and call the `ItemWriter`. So there is no need to have your `ItemProcessor` convert a single element to a `List`. The end result is that instead of a `Chunk<ProcessedObject>` you now get a `Chunk<List<ProcessedObject>>`. If you now call `getItems` on the chunk you will receive a `List<List<ProcessedObject>>`. So it doesn't do what you expect it to do and actually adds complexity. Instead simplify your `ItemProcessor` to just enrich/convert the `InputObject`. Spring Batch will take care of the rest.

```java
@Override
public ProcessedObject process(InputObject input) throws Exception {
    ProcessedObject o = new ProcessedObject();
    try{
         //set metadata to processed object
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        o.setErrorFlag(true);
        o.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return o;
}
```